# Showing textured 3D models in iOS

Tags: ios, safari, 3d

I've been working with software that generates textured 3D models of Roman archaeological artefacts (see [map interface mockup here - click icons for models](http://ecoconsulting.co.uk/romans3d/)). The software ([3DSom Pro](http://www.3dsom.com/)) uses Flash or Java to show the models via a browser.

I need a non-flash/Java solution for web viewing iOS, but WebGL is only supported in Safari's nightly build (or - I understand - for adverts), which excludes the average user.

Has anyone successfully shown textured 3D models in a web browser on iOS? I know Pages (I think) supports native SketchUp files and iOS devices can display 3D, but in a browser...?

Answer (score 3):

While three.js,( a great library for doing in-browser 3D with javascript) also supports canvas rendering instead of just webGL rendering, unfortunately mobilesafari is still fairly unstable in conjunction with three.js' canvasrenderer (what i gather from mrdoob's github discussions, this has been an issue since IOS5)
You could try to find a css3 DOM renderer, but it seems there isn't one available in conjunction with a framework that offers the ability to load textured models for you, which might be a lot of work to realise yourself.

Comment: three.js is great, but from what I can gather over the last few months of research, it seems the enabling by default of WebGL in iOS Safari is long overdue, but probably the most likely future solution.

Comment: Like i said, it supports canvas rendering which should (theoretically) work on your iPad, iPhone and/or iPod Touch. but a bug in the current version of mobilesafari causes it to behave erratically and even crash.
I have not tried three.js with the SVG renderer yet (which should also work in theory)
You can try a canvasrenderer example of three.js here : http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html