# Interactive 3D model without WebGL for iOS

Tags: ios, html, 3d, mobile-safari, webgl

I want to make something similar to this - http://appserv.kfshrc.edu.sa/Default/Health/Anantomy.aspx, but without using flash and able to work on Mobile Safari on iPad.

I played with WebGL, it's great but doesn't work on iOS yet (though it is there in Mobile Safari, but it's just for iAds). I also tried with CSS 3D transformations, but it doesn't work properly. So, what can I use to implement this for iOS Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be worth looking into [three.js](http://threejs.org/), a JavaScript 3d library which allows you to choose canvas, SVG or WebGL as the render target. three.js should make building something like the example you point to in your question fairly straightforward.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592640/showing-textured-3d-models-in-ios), there have been some issues with canvas rendering in mobile Safari, but that was over a year ago so it may have been resolved. You could try some of the [canvas examples](http://threejs.org/examples/) on the three.js site to get an idea of the performance in mobile Safari as of today.

@Nicholas Kyriakides has also pointed out that in his experience SVG render mode has been buggy and not performed as well as WebGL.

Comment: Note, that iOS (<=7) does not support WebGL

Comment: What about the SVG renderer. From what i remember Three.js can use that as well, circumventing the need for WebGL. But i am think last time i checked it was a bit buggy and performance was nowhere near WEBGL.  I think my downvote was invalid so i'll remove it

Comment: @nicholas Kriakides - I haven't played with three for a while so I can't say what the SVG renderer performance is like. I guess you'd just have to test it out and see for yourself. If you could undo the down vote that would be greatly appreciated ;). I did feel it was a bit unjust as it seems like it might be a good fit for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Well i can't upvote because S.O doesn't let me do it without you editing your answer. Just refer to the SVG rendered and i'll try again

Comment: IOS7 does support Three, but only in SVG render mode. It is a good fit but its rather ambiguous the way it is now.

Comment: Updated my answer. For sure it's ambiguous - it was just a suggestion and hopefully I was pretty clear that I wasn't 100% sure it was the right one ;).

Comment: hate to be a gravedigger, but just pointing out that svg performance on ios is just horrible

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck in the past using this: https://code.google.com/p/jsc3d/ 
It worked on everything i tried on, i just had to change some javascript to make it interactive with mobile devices but i think now they took my changes and it should work for touch events.

That rendered with Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE<9, IE>=9, Android Phone, Android Tablet, iPad, iPhone.

However performance is poor.
But its cool i created a model in google sketchup, exported the obj file and then rendered it multiplatform with textures.