# Interactive 3d model for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, metal

Similar to this question

[Interactive 3D model without WebGL for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684360/interactive-3d-model-without-webgl-for-ios)

I don't want to go down the webview/javascript path.

I want something like this

```
http://appserv.kfshrc.edu.sa/Default/Health/Anantomy.aspx
```

in native Metal or Scenekit written in Swift.

I've searched github but haven't come across anything.

Is this even possible?  Reading through the SDKs, I can't see how to activate a surface, edge or vertex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this the easy way, I would suggest using SceneKit. You can make your each section of your human body model using any online 3D model maker, then export each section as a .dae, and import it into a SceneKit project. The default code in a SceneKit project already implements most of the features you would want, you would just have to modify which assets it displays (all of your files instead of ship.dae), change the positions of your models to line up correctly, and modify the handleTap method to display text in your HUD UI inside the `if hitresults.count > 0` block, after the code that is already there. Basically you could modify the block of code to look something like:

```
if hitResults.count > 0 {
            // retrieved the first clicked object
            let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]

            // get its material
            let material = result.node!.geometry!.firstMaterial!

            // highlight it
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

            // on completion - unhighlight
            SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                SCNTransaction.begin()
                SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

                material.emission.contents = UIColor.blackColor()

                SCNTransaction.commit()
            }

            material.emission.contents = UIColor.redColor()

            SCNTransaction.commit()
            //this is where your custom code for handling a touch on an object goes. The variable "result" is the object that was tapped
            self.myLabel.text = "Something Was Tapped"
        }
```

So basically: 1. Make models 2. Put models in program (use the code the default project uses to load the ship) 3. Modify handleTap method to display information on the selected section. Hope it helps :)

Comment: excellent, that's what i'm looking for. are there any frameworks, that would allow a user to modify the .dae model?

Comment: as a test, I found this https://github.com/ryanshelby/Stonehenge which uses SceneKit.  basically he creates individual objects then creates arrays of objects but they are not interactive.  And looking at a way to grab each array object and apply the hitResults.

Comment: Just curious - have you made any progress? What filetype is your 3d model? I want to use .mdl file.

Does SceneKit provide default shaders?